# Bicycle helmet camera for long recording and charging simultaneously

Tags: camera

I am using Mobius action cam 2014 model mounted on my bicycle helmet for recording my journeys. My long trips usually last 8 to 10 hours and this camera can record non-stop for that duration, as it has a feature that it can record while charging. I use a power-bank as power supply for camera. However, on bumpy roads, the videos become shaky - there is no video stabilization feature during recording. I have studied features of GoPro HERO10 that has video stabilization, but it cannot record and charge in parallel, we need to change batteries.

I need suggestion regarding camera that has at least follow features:

1. Should be able to record and charge simultaneously
2. Should have built-in video stabilization

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  I'm afraid that questions for shopping recommendations are considered off-topic here because this month's answer might not be useful next year, or even next month.  You might want to take the [tour].

Comment: Thanks for the reply... actually I saw there were some posts regarding that topic (though a bit old), so I posted here thinking of it not off-topic. This forum has very experienced cyclists so I just wanted an opinion. I tried to find my answer in the provided link but couldn't find. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Older posts are not a great indication of on-topicness.  Consider that you're asking about a camera with certain features, to be used while cycling.  If you take the bike out of the question, then the main point of the camera is unchanged.  So this is more about the camera and therefore could be better on **maybe** https://photo.stackexchange.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/  I'm not sure of their rules, so checking in their chat room might be good.

Comment: @Criggie off-topic for photo.se (they're quite strict on video).  I don't know about video.se.  There's always https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ of course, but that's pretty quiet

Comment: ... that said there are some aspects to the question that could be addressed here, about how an arbitrary camera can be set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research I resolved to the following solution. Please note that my solution is not intended to provide "recommendations" for any specific product or brand.

There are two ways we can achieve video stabilization with longer battery life. One option is through your smart phone camera. I have an oppo reno 5 smart phone and I discovered that it has an option of recording "ultra steady" video. To my surprise that option reduced much of the shaking. We can connect smart phone to chest strap and connected with power bank (placed in belly pouch) to increase battery life. The second way is to use some camera with built-in video stabilization features. GoPro Hero 10 / 11 by default do not support simultaneous recording and charging. However, we can still charge and record with these cameras by removing the battery protection cover and connecting charging cable with camera and power bank, keeping in mind that camera will not longer be water proof.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a bodge for charging and recording on my [ActiveOn CX](https://droidhorizon.com/activeon-cx-action-cam-review/), which uses a waterproof case.  A similar method should work for other cameras that are waterproof in the same way, so long as the USB port is no nearer the case hinge than in this case.

The actual camera can run off USB power while recording, otherwise it has about 3 hours battery life on timelapse mode and less shooting video.

I bought a 2nd case (actually a whole 2nd camera sold as "spares and repairs" but functional).  Then I drilled/filed a hole in the spare case to pass through a USB cable. The plug needed trimming down with a knife.  By greasing the hole and surrounding plastic I could build up hot glue around the plug without gluing it to the case.  While not completely waterproof it's protected from light rain.  I reckon recording in heavy rain would be rather pointless.

[image: Modified ActiveOn CX, parts]
[image: Modified ActiveOn CX, assembled]

I have used this camera on my handlebars a few times; on a smooth road the video is [pretty decent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOt2b1dmzaA).  On road, no stabilisation is probably better anyway.

I keep meaning to attach the unmodified housing to my commuting  helmet, though 720p with the wide-angle lens is only enough  for vehicle number plates at pretty close range and the police need a clear view.  Even with an external battery I'm not sure how this camera would do on my longest rides - I could have done with being able to report a few dodgy cars after 24-27 hours.

Comment: Thank you. Nice solution.